# How to get an Fn which calls a Java method?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure. I wrote this code to recursively walk a directory.

```
(tree-seq #(.isDirectory %1) #(.listFiles %1) (File. "/my-directory"))
```

Why can't I use `.isDirectory` as a first-class function in Clojure? Is there a better way to rewrite this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java methods aren't clojure functions because you can't call a method on its own; you have to call a method on an object, and it has to be an object of the type that the method expects. In other words, in java, a method cannot be fully separated from its defining class (at least not efficiently).

An alternative to  #(.foo %) would be (memfn foo), which hardly anyone uses anymore after #(...) was introduced.

Answer (score 7):

Joost is spot on about Java methods not being first class functions.

As an approach to dealing with this, I usually like to wrap Java functions in a Clojure function (or find a library that does this already), then it is easy to use them in an idiomatic first-class way:

```
(defn directory? [^java.io.File file]
  (.isDirectory file))

(defn list-files [^java.io.File file]
  (.listFiles %1))

(tree-seq directory? list-files (File. "/my-directory"))
```

This is a few more lines of code, but has the following advantages:

- You can add type hints in your functions to avoid reflection (as above)
- The final code is cleaner and more idiomatic
- You have abstracted away from the underlying Java interop

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the [sourcecode of file-seq](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/d0c380d9809fd242bec688c7134e900f0bbedcac/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4378) (which uses a tree-seq) to see how it works.

By the way: your code works perfectly well for me. I just have to use java.io.File instead of File in the REPL so it knows the Java class.

Answer (score 1):

You've already been given the correct answers, but just to add a bit more Clojure idiomatic code, I'd also use

```
#(.foo %)
```

as Joost Diepenmaat did (yet I believed it might've been overlooked).

I would also suggest reading [Listing files in a directory in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566531/listing-files-in-a-directory-in-clojure).