# Clojure list subfolders in resources in uberjar

Tags: java, file, jar, clojure

I have a folder structure like this:

- resources

  - a

    - b

      - x.txt
    - c

      - x.txt

I've created my runnable jar with `lein uberjar`.

When running my jar, I want to list the subfolders of `a`.

I know I can get the contents of resources/a/b/x.txt using clojure.java.io

```
(slurp (clojure.java.io/resource "a/b/x.txt"))
```

But I can't find a simple way to list the subfolders.

`(clojure.java.io/file (clojure.java.io/resource "a"))` just results in a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file` because it isn't a file, it's a resource inside the jar file.

Is there a library that does this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list the files inside a JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file)

Comment: Neither of those show either 1) a simple way to do this 2) a library that does this. I refuse to accept that the answer to this is a massive bunch of java code.

Comment: well.. it is kind of a trivial task, to translate java code to clojure.

Comment: This can be done with a one-liner in shell (`zipinfo -1 ...`). Do you need to do it from/with clojure code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the port of code from the java specific answer:

```
(ns my-project.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as cs])
  (:import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream)
  (:gen-class))

(defrecord HELPER [])

(defn get-code-location []
  (when-let [src (.getCodeSource (.getProtectionDomain HELPER))]
    (.getLocation src)))

(defn list-zip-contents [zip-location]
  (with-open [zip-stream (ZipInputStream. (.openStream zip-location))]
    (loop [dirs []]
      (if-let [entry (.getNextEntry zip-stream)]
        (recur (conj dirs (.getName entry)))
        dirs))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println (some->> (get-code-location)
                    list-zip-contents
                    (filter #(cs/starts-with? % "a/")))))
```

Being put to a main namespace and run with jar will output all the paths in the `/resources/a` folder..

```
java -jar ./target/my-project-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar 
;;=> (a/ a/b/ a/b/222.txt a/222.txt)
```

Also some quick research lead me to this library:
https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

it shortens the code, but also requires some dependencies for the project (i guess it could be undesirable):

```
[org.reflections/reflections "0.9.11"]
[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
[com.google.guava/guava "23.0"]
```

and the code is something like this:

```
(ns my-project.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as cs])
  (:import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream
           [org.reflections
            Reflections
            scanners.ResourcesScanner
            scanners.Scanner
            util.ClasspathHelper
            util.ConfigurationBuilder])
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [conf (doto (ConfigurationBuilder.)
               (.setScanners (into-array Scanner [(ResourcesScanner.)]))
               (.setUrls (ClasspathHelper/forClassLoader (make-array ClassLoader 0))))]
    (println
     (filter #(cs/starts-with? % "a/")
             (.getResources (Reflections. conf) #".*")))))
```

Comment: I've accepted this as the correct answer - which it technically is. The complexity of the solution tells me I'm trying to do the wrong thing entirely.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach (but I must admit that it doesn't feel entirely satisfactory) is to read the contents at compile time.  Assuming you have a function `list-files` that gives you the list from your project root directory:

```clj
(defmacro compile-time-filelist []
  `'~(list-files "resources/a"))
```

or

```
(defmacro compile-time-filelist []
  (vec (list-files "resources/a")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively list all items in a dir using `file-seq` function. Example:

```
(let [files (file-seq (clojure.java.io/file "resources"))
      dir? #(.isDirectory %)]
  (map dir? files))
```

You can also call `.listFiles` or `.list` on a `File` object. The first gives file objects, the second gives filenames.

You can find additional examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566531/listing-files-in-a-directory-in-clojure) and [here](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/cookbooks/files_and_directories.html).

Comment: The challenge here is that when running from an uberjar, there's no longer a directory—just contents of a zip file.